# Как быстро импортировать 350 000 товаров в WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть csv файл на 350 000 товаров, и мне нужно импортировать их в woocomerce, но импорт происходит очень долго (несколько дней). Как можно быстро импортировать такое количество товаров?

Comment: Делать надо программно, не плагином. Не через админку, а запуском отдельного php процесса на сервере без ограничений по времени. И для ускорения - переводить базу в режим транзакции (ну хотя бы на 1000 товаров).

Comment: Я бы наверное загуглил что-от типа  "wp-cli import woocommerce"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложно сказать однозначно, почему такой долгий импорт. Нужно смотреть сам файл csv.

Даже, если у каждого поста огромное количество полей, время не должно доходить до таких диких значений. Очевидная проблема может быть в том, что в файле CSV есть ссылки на изображения и WP вынужден при импорте их загружать.

Я бы сделал отдельную выгрузку изображений через FTP (можно дописать парсер при необходимости), а затем сопоставил бы посты с изображениями.